# How understand image_dataset_from_directory() and use it as X, y input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I made a simple CNN and to allocate datasets I used image_dataset_from_directory() func

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  check_dir,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Now I was interested to create graphs like RocCurve and confusion_matrix, but I can't understand what should I put as an input?

Comment: I finushed my train and want to do these graphs based on it

Comment: code of my model: https://github.com/AliveGorilla/CNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, if someone will face this problem

If you create cycle

```
for x, y in test_ds:
...
# Code
...
```

x - numpy array of images
y - numpy array of true labels

UPD:

```
predictions = np.array([]) 
labels =  np.array([]) 
scores = np.array([]) 
////////////
for x, y in test_ds:   
    predictions = np.concatenate([predictions, np.argmax(new_model.predict(x), axis=1)])   
    labels = np.concatenate([labels, y.numpy()])   
    scores = np.concatenate([scores, new_model.predict(x)[:, 1]])
```

Comment: I am also searching to solve the same problem. Could you please share the sample code?

I created an image binary classification model using CNN. I created train_ds, val_ds and test_ds just like you.

I want to create a confusion matrix after model.fit(), but I'm having trouble because I don't know what true label and prediction label are. 

thank you.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, but wasn't checking the forum. 
If you still need so here the example.

I update the answer with code

Answer (score 0):

Depends basically on what you want and what do you use to create it.

For example to create a confusion matrix you can use the `confusion_matrix` functions provided by sklearn ([link here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)). In this case the function want as input the true label and the predicted label

Comment: Yes, I saw doc. But I can't understand what is "y_true, y_pred" for my code

Comment: Let's take an example: you want to classify image and say if image represent a cat or not. So the label will be 0 if the image has a cat and 1 if image has no cat.

y_true will be the true label of the image while y_pred will be the output of your classifier (in your case the neural network)

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I just don't know how to get these arrays from such datasets.
I have 2 clasess and around 3,000 pics for each.

Comment: You will obtain y_pred directly from the neural network. You input each image in the network and the label you obtain is a component of y_pred (i.e. for the i-th image you will obtain the i-th element of y_pred)

Comment: Regarding y_true it's a bit that I don't use tensorflow so I don't remember how tensorflow dataset works but basically y_true should be a vector with the true label of the data so you should have it for the training

Comment: Ok, I'll try to check it. But if it help here is my full code: https://github.com/AliveGorilla/CNN

Comment: I check briefly your code. When you plot your data you also cycle throug the true label (`for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):`). That variable that you called label is the true label of the data so y_true should be a vector containing all that labels